# how to change the image in a gridview dynamically after completing one level

Tags: android

I have an application which is having n images on the gridview, initially user will click on the image at index 0 and play the game completes it. Next time the image in at the index 1 should be changed. How can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved this by calling notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter and by calling invalidateViews() on gridview